# Intext citation in IEEE format

Tags: formatting, citing, ieee-style

I am trying to change the citations of my bibliography so that it uses IEEE format for the `\cite` command. Currently, `\cite{...}`  the generates output  like (1) whereas I want it to appear as [1].

Here is a snippet of my file:

```
\usepackage[]{natbib}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\input{Includes/01_Introduction}

\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{Includes/References.bib}
```

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to set the format to numbers in the natbib: such that it becomes `\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}`.

Comment: Use `\usepackage[noadjust]{cite}` instead of `natbib`